# jquery toggle between two buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to make a easy menu with jquery but seems that im doing something wrong can anyone tell me what im doing wrong... i check other threads but i can't find the solution to this problem, thanks for your time guys

```
    <nav id="header">
    <ul>
    <li class="one"><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li class="two"><a href="#">two</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </nav>   
    <div class="one-div">
    <div>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two-div">
    <div>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>text here</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </code>

    // in the css of the div i got the display:"none";

    $('.one').click(function() {
    if ($(".one-div").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".one-div").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
    $(".one-div").hide();
    }
    });

    $('.two').click(function() {
    if ($(".two-div").is(":hidden")) {
    $(".two-div").slideDown("slow");
    } else {
    $(".two-div").hide();
    }
    });
```

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same ID `header`.

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: on click on the first i like to hide it before showing the second one... thats my main problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS

```
.one { display:block; }
.two { display:none; }
```

JS

```
var buttons = $(".one,.two").on("click", function(){
    buttons.slideToggle();
})
```

Comment: `.one` and `.one-div` are not the same thing.